# CSS: How to keep a hover transition smooth while another animation is running

Tags: css, animation, hover, css-animations

I created a button. This button is defined by these CSS properties:

```
#button {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 3px solid #F1F2F0;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: #02BFC1;
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right:0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    animation: blinker 2s ease infinite;
}
```

This button blinks using the animation `blinker` that smoothly changes the `background-color` from a darker to a lighter blue, defined like this:

```
@keyframes blinker {  
    50% { background-color: #03FCFF; }
}
```

It also has a hover animation:

```
#button:hover {
    background-color: #F37C2B;
    transform: scale(1.1);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 70px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    animation-name: none;
}
```

My problem is this: the hover animation used to be completely smooth before I added the blinker animation. Now, it just instantly changes `background-color`to the orange, while the `transform: scale(1.1)` still changes smoothly.

How can I make it so that hovering the button pauses the `blinker` animation and smoothly changes `background-color`, and that the animation resumes by mouse-leaving the button? If possible, I would like to use only CSS for this and no js.

If you prefer, you can modify this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JocaPinto/f62rkrpo/1/) to respond.

**EDIT:** This doesn't work only on chrome, how can I make it so it does?

Answer (score 0):

You have too many things going on in your CSS. As a general rule try to **keep things as simple as possible** if you want your code to be fast and efficient.

Here is your working code with some explanations:

```css
button {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  border: 3px solid #F1F2F0;
  background-color: #02BFC1;
  margin: 30px auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  animation: 2s ease infinite blinker;
  transition: background-color .5s ease, transform .5s ease, box-shadow .5s ease; /* it is best to select the properties you want to transition instead of using 'all' */
}

@keyframes blinker {
  50% {
    background-color: #03FCFF;
  }
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #F37C2B;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 70px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  animation: none;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<button></button>
```

Don't forget to use the prefixes needed for your project.

Comment: You still don't fix the non smoothness when hovering?

Comment: @JocaPinto Which browser are you using? It's pretty smooth for me in Firefox 48.

Comment: You are right, it doesn't work smoothly in Chrome. It's a bug for which I didn't find any CSS solution (except changing your effect), sorry.

Comment: there must be a way though